# How to process centered multi colored text in Tess4j and Tesseract?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

How can Tess4J and Tesseract be configured to correctly recognize centered multi color text?

Tesseract is only able to recognize the first and last line in the following image:

[image]

I tried converting the image to greyscale but the output remains the same:

`Executioners Pole Hook * *
esi yee
+50% more damage when your target is below 40% health`

As a workaround, I can split the image into multiple files but would prefer not needing to do that.

The images are PNG, but have not noticed any change between png and jpeg.

Comment: This is your extemporaneous Results. I got it to show the middle line (99%) by a simple do - no further processing. So I don't KNOW what you are talking about.

Comment: @gpasch are you using tesseract v5 installed without any additional packages or did you add languages or fonts to it? I keep getting inconsistent result when running tess4j

Comment: Have you tried with different PSM values, and image preprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the quality of the output by using these parameters:

```
           instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", "7");
           instance.setLanguage("eng");
           instance.setOcrEngineMode(0);
```

The last one forces Tesseract to use a local dictionary only. After enabling it I downloaded the English dictionary from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

I am now also converting the bitmaps to greyscale as well as scaling them up if the height is to short so that each bitmap has at least 70 pixels.